# cannot assign a value to a character variable with scanf in c?

Tags: c, variables, char, scanf

sorry for the somewhat vague title. I am trying to run a simple program where the user inputs one character and it is immediately recalled. 
So far i have

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char ch;
printf("Enter one char\n");
scanf_s("%c", &ch);
printf("the char is %c.\n",ch);
return(0);
}
```

But for some reason this returns "the char is ." and i have no idea why.

if i change it to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int ch;
printf("Enter one char\n");
scanf_s("%d", &ch);
printf("the char is %d.\n",ch);
return(0);
}
```

it works fine and returns the integer that I entered so i dont think the problem is with the codes structure. For some reason i just seem to be unable to assign a value to a ch variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be checking the return value from `scanf_s()` to ensure you are getting a valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using is a secured version of scanf and always remember the **scanf_s** needs the **buffer size argument to work** so in order to make scanf_s work in your program use this

```
scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);
```

Where **1 is the buffer size argument**. HTH :)

**EDIT:** And one more thing why your program is working when you make it ch as int because scanf_s doesn't need the buffer size argument for integer,floats but **whenever you're reading a character, strings, arrays you should mandatorily provide the buffer size argument.**

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked beautifully. I have been searching for a solution to this for hours. I did not expect such a helpful and immediate response. I would love to hear about this buffer size argument and the relevance of the number 1 if you would care to elaborate or recommend a good source.

Comment: You're welcome :) check this link [scanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try
`scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);`

valter

Comment: +1: C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) Annex K (K.3.5.3.2 The `fscanf_s` function) says: _The `fscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf` except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion
specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a
`*`). The first of these arguments is the same as for `fscanf`. That argument is
immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
`rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument
of the pair._ […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…] _If the first argument points to a scalar object, it is considered to be an array of
one element._  There's also a long footnote.  The same rules apply to `scanf_s()`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace scanf_s() with scanf() as scanf_s() is Microsoft specific. I am having code running fine with scanf().